# Inserting the value of objects in an object into an array (map takes too long) so I can pass the array to Dropdown (React Native - Expo)

Tags: arrays, json, object

It needs to pass values (**name**) from the object that is in the object to the array.

I'm doing it now using maps, but since there are a lot of objects, it takes half a minute.

**Array of objects that I get using the API:**

https://pastebin.com/SPpbzwn3

```
[
{
    "name": "A",
    "schoolCount": 2
},
{
    "name": "B",
    "schoolCount": 1
},
{
    "name": "C",
    "schoolCount": 1
}]
```

**What I need to get:**

```
["A","B","C"]
```

**How do I now get values from an object into an array:**

```
.then(function (response) {
    response.data.map(({ name }) => {
      setCity((city) => [...city, name]);
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends. Is:

"setCity" created by useState?? if yes each interation of map is causing render so I am not suprised that it takes time.

I would rather set entire array once it is mapped into object by e.g. setCities to speed it up.

Comment: Thanks lot, It was because of the rendering